# docker-compose rebuild image of one service and use it

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to get docker-compose to:

- rebuild the image of a certain service (only source code has changed, not the Dockerfile)
- re-"up" just that service within docker-compose, using the new image

I find I have to perform a `docker build` on that service's Dockerfile, then perform a `docker-compose up <service-name>` for the new image to be used.

Is there a way I can do this just using docker-compose?

Below is the long meandering path I took to get the new image to be used in docker-compose.

---

#### Journey to get docker-compose to use new image

This is the current docker-compose setup.

```
 Container          Repository          Tag       Image Id       Size
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
books-server   books-server            v06      c35c65375942   13.37 MB
hasura-proxy   hasura/graphql-engine   v1.3.2   a499c4b91ba4   48.34 MB
nginx-proxy    jwilder/nginx-proxy     latest   fcb5a96e19c1   160.6 MB
postgres       postgres                12       7b9cf7d827b4   314 MB
```

I make a change to **books-server**, the underlying source code, which gets compiled into an executable, and I want that image rebuilt and used in docker-compose.

If I issue a:

```
> docker-compose up --detach --build books-server
```

Result:

```
books-server is up-to-date
```

Try:

```
> docker-compose build --no-cache books-server
```

Result:

```
books-server uses an image, skipping
```

Try:

```
> docker-compose up --build --no-deps --force-recreate -d books-server
```

Result:

```
Recreating books-server ... done
```

Check:

```
> docker-compose images
```

Result

```
 Container          Repository          Tag       Image Id       Size
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
books-server   books-server            v06      c35c65375942   13.37 MB
hasura-proxy   hasura/graphql-engine   v1.3.2   a499c4b91ba4   48.34 MB
nginx-proxy    jwilder/nginx-proxy     latest   fcb5a96e19c1   160.6 MB
postgres       postgres                12       7b9cf7d827b4   314 MB
```

Image id of books-server is still `c35c65375942`

Try:

```
> docker-compose restart books-server
Restarting books-server ... done
```

Check images:

Still using image Id `c35c65375942`

```
> docker-compose images

 Container          Repository          Tag       Image Id       Size
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
books-server   books-server            v06      c35c65375942   13.37 MB
hasura-proxy   hasura/graphql-engine   v1.3.2   a499c4b91ba4   48.34 MB
nginx-proxy    jwilder/nginx-proxy     latest   fcb5a96e19c1   160.6 MB
postgres       postgres                12       7b9cf7d827b4   314 MB
```

Try:

I change to the books-server directory, perform a docker build on its Dockerfile using the same tag (`books-server:v06`)

```
> cd ..\books-server\
> docker build -t books-server:v06 .
```

Result:

A new image is built `55ea56a70aa9` and tagged

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  73.43MB
Step 1/21 : FROM google/dart-runtime-base AS dart-runtime
...<snip>...
Removing intermediate container bff4c43f6bf0
 ---> 55ea56a70aa9
Successfully built 55ea56a70aa9
Successfully tagged books-server:v06
```

I check `docker images`:

And see the tag has been removed from image `c35c65375942` and given to `55ea56a70aa9`

```
> docker images

REPOSITORY                        TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
<none>                            <none>              d50d6ccf14a1        About a minute ago   798MB
books-server                      v06                 55ea56a70aa9        About a minute ago   13.4MB
<none>                            <none>              c35c65375942        31 minutes ago       13.4MB
```

I check `docker-compose images`:

```
 Container          Repository          Tag       Image Id       Size
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
books-server   <none>                  <none>   c35c65375942   13.37 MB
hasura-proxy   hasura/graphql-engine   v1.3.2   a499c4b91ba4   48.34 MB
nginx-proxy    jwilder/nginx-proxy     latest   fcb5a96e19c1   160.6 MB
postgres       postgres                12       7b9cf7d827b4   314 MB
```

books-server is still using the old image, now running anonymously, since the image tag has been reappropriated to `55ea56a70aa9`

I try a restart of the service in docker-compose:

```
> docker-compose restart books-server
Restarting books-server ... done
```

I check docker-compose images, and see the old image `c35c65375942`  still being used.

```
 Container          Repository          Tag       Image Id       Size
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
books-server   <none>                  <none>   c35c65375942   13.37 MB
hasura-proxy   hasura/graphql-engine   v1.3.2   a499c4b91ba4   48.34 MB
nginx-proxy    jwilder/nginx-proxy     latest   fcb5a96e19c1   160.6 MB
postgres       postgres                12       7b9cf7d827b4   314 MB
```

I re-up docker-compose and finally see the new image (`55ea56a70aa9`) in use:

```
> docker-compose up -d books-server
Recreating books-server ... done
> docker-compose images
 Container          Repository          Tag       Image Id       Size
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
books-server   books-server            v06      55ea56a70aa9   13.37 MB
hasura-proxy   hasura/graphql-engine   v1.3.2   a499c4b91ba4   48.34 MB
nginx-proxy    jwilder/nginx-proxy     latest   fcb5a96e19c1   160.6 MB
postgres       postgres                12       7b9cf7d827b4   314 MB
```

---

#### Summary

Is there a `docker-compose` command that can rebuild the service image and restart that service or must it be done using a `docker build Dockerfile` and `docker-compose up <service>`?

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Adding your `docker-compose` file to the question might help. Also, have a look at [build](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build) if you're not using that already.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to timsmelik comment I realized I wasn't using a `build:` directive in my `books-server` service in docker-compose.yml and only a tagged image name, which docker-compose doesn't easily replace/use when a new version is produced.

Removing the `image:` directive and replacing it with a relative `build:` target,
a simple `docker-compose up --build -d books-server` is rebuilding the service and using it within the docker-compose project.

```
  books-server:
    # ↓ new build directive
    build: ../books-server
    # ↓ old image directive, removed
    # image: books-server:v06
    container_name: books-server
    <other settings>...
```